# Random value in objective c gives incorrect numbers

Tags: objective-c, random, arc4random

I need to get random float values in range [-1, 1].

```
    CGFloat max = 1;
    CGFloat min = -1;
```

I use following code:

```
((float)arc4random()/RAND_MAX)*(max-min)+min
```

But i get value between -1.007 to 2.879 and so on. Where i have a problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAND_MAX` is not the maximum value of `arc4random()`. `arc4random()` returns numbers over the whole range of `u_int32_t` (0 to (2^32)-1), which is a larger range than `rand()`.

Also, `float` is not big enough to hold all values in that range to full precision.

Try:

```
((double)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX) * (max - min) + min
```